# Why CSS style don't work with the images?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to minimize the picture but nothing happens.

Images are fetched from a function that brings the name of the image from the databases to be displayed in the array.

```css
/* Products   */
.imagesPanel {
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border:solid 1px #d1d1d1;
}
.imagesPanel .msg {
    text-align: center;

}
.imagesPanel img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-xs-12 imagesPanel">
    <?php $imgNameFunction = imgSelectV2("products",$row['ID']);
          if ($imgNameFunction == null) { ?>
              <p class="msg"><?php echo lang('THERE_ARE_NO_IMAGES_FOR_THIS_PRODUCT'); ?></p>
    <?php } else {
        foreach ($imgNameFunction as $imgName){?>
            <div class="col-xs-3 itemShow">
                <img src="<?php echo $dir_uploadedImage.$imgName['ImgName']; ?>">
            </div>

        <?php }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

But the result is shown at this image:

[image]

Could you please help?

Comment: it is probably overriding the css. try .imagesPanel img {
    width: 200px !important;
    height: 200px !important;
}

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML? We cannot guess what the PHP is outputting. Also, check the developer console to check wether or not your CSS affected the image

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: Look at the browser debugger and trace the css down to this image. You are a Lead Developer so you probably already know how to do that

Answer (score -1, accepted):

thanks for your help
as **tech2017**

> it is probably overriding the css. try .imagesPanel img { width: 200px
>   !important; height: 200px !important; } – tech2017 37 mins ago